# reacting to message just created

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to make the bot react to it's own message. I am making a !vote command and it can make a message saying "Cast your vote: " already. I want to make a reaction to that new message, like an example, where it reacts with a checkmark and a red x for people to click on. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending a message returns a promise with said message. Resolve it and react to it.

```js
message.channel.send(...)
    .then(msg => msg.react(...));

// or

const newMsg = await message.channel.send(...);
newMsg.react(...);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However I am a bit confused about how to react twice. I want to react with a checkmark and an x. How can I do both with the first format

Comment: Open the function with curly braces and call `msg.react()` again

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
  if (msg.content === `!vote`) {
    msg.channel.send(`Cast your vote:`).then(msg => {
      msg.react("✅");
      msg.react("❎");
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: hey this doesn't work. It reacts to the message saying "!vote" and not the new message.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you meant. This was what I thought you meant